# How to calculate the total difference between 2 timestamps of every row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with three columns:

ID - starttime (in timestamp) - endtime (in timestamp)

How can I calculate the total minutes of this table, so the sum of each timestampdifferece of each row?

```
<input name="datum" type="date" class="form-control" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>">

<input name="starttime" type="time" class="form-control" value="<?php echo date("H:i",time()); ?>">

$datum = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($_POST['datum']));
$starttime= date('H:i', strtotime($_POST['starttime']));
$starttimestamp = strtotime($datum.$starttime);
mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO plan VALUES (NULL, ".my_id.", ".$starttimestamp.", ".$name.")");
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: . . You still have not shown what the data looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `timestampdiff()` to get the difference between the timestamps and `sum()` to sum them up.

```
SELECT sum(timestampdiff(minute, starttime, endtime))
       FROM elbat;
```

Comment: It doesn't work:
I have the following rows:
1 - 1545583164 - 1545590375
2 - 1545593975 - 1545597575

But it returns NULL

Comment: @itranger: What's the data type?

Comment: The data type is varchar @sticky bit

Comment: @itranger: Bad decision. Redesign the table and use a proper data type. Meanwhile find a way to convert the strings in a timestamp.

Comment: I agree with @stickybit on the bad design decision, but have also been hamstrung myself by poor design decisions made by people before me. My question is how does `1545583164 ` translate into a date/time?

Comment: FROM_UNIXTIME function can be used to convert these timestamps into datetime. However, this is not needed as Gordon Linoff's solutions should work.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your "timestamps" are really unix timestamps -- the number of seconds since 1970-01-01.  If so, simply arithmetic does what you want:

```
SELECT SUM(endtime - starttime) / 60 as total_minutes
FROM elbat;
```

Comment: I've edited the post. How can I convert these timestamps to unix timestamps?

Comment: @itranger . . . Based on your comment to the now-deleted answer, these appear to be unix timestamps.